# How to run Selenium chromedriver headless while using a user profile

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, headless

I have coded a script to perform some actions while logged into my youtube account, using my Chrome user data folder:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

driver.get(https://youtube.com)
driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot.png")

thing = driver.find_element_by_xpath(                 
    'someXpath')
thing.click()
```

It works perfectly without the line:

> options.add_argument('--headless')

However, when "headless" is added as an option, the screenshot taken by *driver.get_screenshot_as_file* shows that chrome is prompting a login to a google account, indicating that the specified chrome profile is not being used.
If possible, I'd like to use both headless mode and use my chrome profile at the same time. Thanks for any help.